# Reconstruction function for scanlines in IDAT chunk

Tags: python, filter, png, zlib

I'm trying to write png reader using python and zlib. I do not understand what to do after I've decompressed IDAT content. My code now (imagine that we have only one IDAT chunk):

```
    ...
    def IDAT(self, chunk_size):
        data = self.f.read(chunk_size)
        raw_colors = zlib.decompress(data)
        self.raw_color_values.extend(raw_colors)
        self.f.read(4)
        self.processIDAT()

    def processIDAT(self):

        Recon = []

        i = 0
        bytesPerPixel = self.bit_depth // 8
        if self.color_type == 2:
            bytesPerPixel = (self.bit_depth // 8) * 3
        for y in range(self.file_height):  # for each scanline
            processRow = [0] * self.file_width
            filter_type = self.raw_color_values[y * (self.file_width * bytesPerPixel + 1)]
            i += 1
            for x in range(self.file_width):  # for each byte in scanline
                color_index = self.raw_color_values[y * (self.file_width * bytesPerPixel + 1) + 1 + x]
                i += 1
                if filter_type == 0:  # None
                    Recon_x = color_index
                elif filter_type == 1:  # Sub
                    # ??????
                elif filter_type == 2:  # Up
                    # ??????
                elif filter_type == 3:  # Average
                    # ??????
                elif filter_type == 4:  # Paeth
                    Recon_x = color_index + self.PaethPredictor() # what are params here?
                else:
                    print('unknown filter type: ' + str(filter_type))
                Recon.append(Recon_x & 0xff)  # truncation to byte

        return Recon

    def PaethPredictor(self, a, b, c):
        p = a + b - c
        pa = abs(p - a)
        pb = abs(p - b)
        pc = abs(p - c)
        if pa <= pb and pa <= pc:
            Pr = a
        elif pb <= pc:
            Pr = b
        else:
            Pr = c
        return Pr
```

According to [official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#9-table91) I have to implement `Recon` function. What this function does? Are there any implementation references?

Comment: The implementation reference is [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas for `Recon` are right there in [the document you linked](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#9-table91):

[image: x is the byte, a is left of x, b is above x, c is left of b]
[image: filter formulas]
[image: Paeth algorithm]

Comment: can you explain me this simple case? For example, I have decompressed RGB(int triplet for a pixel) image with 2 pixels width in 1d array, but not reconstructed `[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`. Every scanline starts with filter number, here we see only 1 type filter, which is sub. Let `Recon` be 1d array with reconstructed values. How should `Recon` look like after reconstruction? `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]` (we just add left values to original value)? I guess I need to understand this for correct implementation.

Comment: No. The filter is applied to R, G, and B independently. So you end up with `0 0 0 1 1 1` for your example. Read section 4.5.4.